# Detect other iPhones in a range

Tags: c++, ios

I'm looking to create a mobile app on IOS devices before I started I just needed to check up on one thing. How can I detect other IOS mobile devices within local rage e.g same room, same train, etc..

I want to be able to do it while the phone is locked, so bluetooth wouldn't be a great example as most people have it turned off.

Thanks!

Comment: You could make the speaker periodically shout "Hands up if you have an iPhone!" or something like that :) P.S. I didn't downvote you.

Comment: `most people have it turned off` Yeah, to prevent being discovered. This "requirement" is incredibly creepy and suspicious. Ultimately it's _none of your business_ who else in the room has an iOS device on them.

Comment: They would have to have the app downloaded and be using it to find out, its part of the app. Just like the nintendo has street pass it would be something you opt into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application has to send its location to the server.
Then the server knows where every devices that shared its location are.
Then your application can ask "who is around?" to your server... and your server calculates (let's suppose within a radius of 2 miles) who is around... and sends back to you.

It doesn't have anything to do with bluetooth. It's done via regular internet.

Comment: Thanks for your comment big help in what I'm looking to achieve thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For other users of your app who want to be discovered you could use Bluetooth LE and the new iBeacon support added in iOS 7. Each user would have to launch your app and give it permission to start "advertising" their presence. However, the range of Bluetooth LE is like 10-20 meters (I forget the exact figure) and that will go down in "RF hostile" environments.

If everybody's connected to the same WiFi network you could use Bonjour.

Another option, as suggested by Wagner, above, is to have the devices send their locations to a central server.